# Firestore allow document creation if subcolletion of user exists

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement some user groups in Firestore.
In order to keep access to the right level (as far as the firestore documentation says) I must allocate data in subcollection.

In my case I approached as follows:

- I have a collection `groups` where I store `admin`, `users` and all the related data.
- Then when a user creates/join a group I add a subcollection in the user `/user/{userId}/group/{groupId}` to signal that he is in a group (a user cannot be in more than 1 group), this should allow me to keep it private.

I am not able to set up the right rule on the `groups` document creation as I'm not able to verify that `/user/{userId}/group/*` does not exists.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I'm open to change the implementation if something else will be more fit, but users must not be able to see each others groups.

I tried multiple iterations of this rule:

```
match /groups/{groupId} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/group).size() == 0;
}
```

or

```
match /groups/{mineId} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in security rules to check whether a **collection** exists. The only options are to check whether a document exists, or get its data. So you will have to modify your data model to allow the use-case based on those options.

For example, consider **also** storing the groups that the user is a member of in their `/user/{userId}` document - so that you can get it from there in the security rules.